# form_for label how to append customed string in for attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I want to  append `123` after the label for value,
But it didn't work.

```
        = f.label(:server_information, "123") do
          = f.radio_button :server_information, server_type , class: "need_check"
          = server_type
```

Comment: You're specifying the body of the `<label>` tag by passing a block to the method. You need to add the `"123"` inside that block.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just try this:

```
= f.label :server_information.to_s+"123"
```

This produces following label:

```
Server Information 123
```

Tell me if this is what you want or did it help you out

Answer (score 0):

```
= f.label(:server_information) do
    123
    = f.radio_button :server_information, server_type , class: "need_check"
    = server_type
```